# How to embed Power Point on html page

Tags: php, html

I wanna insert PowerPoint file from my host to my Web Page. But without Google Drive. 
Can i do it with

> `<code><object type=...</code>`

Comment: No, there is no embedded PowerPoint player.

Comment: Why. How Does Google, Slideshare do that?

Comment: [How to embed powerpoint into website](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/embed-a-presentation-in-a-web-page-or-blog-19668a1d-2299-4af3-91e1-ae57af723a60)

You can do it like this!

Answer (score 0):

There is few ways for embedding a powerpoint file into your HTML, if you do not prefer using Google docs, you can always use SLIDESHARE or DROPBOX or any third party that provides similar service.

If you prefer to host your files on your own host then you would need to setup a flash player for powerpoint files.

[This link](http://www.wildapricot.com/blogs/newsblog/2008/07/07/4-ways-to-put-a-powerpoint-presentation-on-your-web-site) seems to have few examples for such players.